# Is there a key shortcut for "Presentation Mode" on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, presentation, mode

Currently using Lubuntu 16.04, old HP CQ20 laptop, with the LXDE and the XFCE power manager.

Currently I just right click on the XFCE power manager icon to tick enable but it's clunky to do.

I would rather have a quick key to enable/disable presentation mode when watching videos, recording cams and doing doc/powerpoint like presentations etc.

Is there a way to action a keyboard binding for this? Or is there a small program that extends this Presentation Mode function. e.g. selective programs, timers etc?

Comment: Could you please explain what is meant by "presentation mode"? How do you currently enable/disable it? And what is the connection with "LXDE and the XFCE power manager"?

Comment: Do you mean "full screen" mode? That should be F11.

Answer (score 4):

It's ok thanks I found the answer

Presentation mode keeps the screen on and stops the screen from blanking as set by the power management settings for the purposes of displaying powerpoint docs, impress or other documents for on a projector for work purposes, for watching video, or keeping the screen on for any other reason.

**To toggle manually with mouse:** Right click on XFCE Power Manager icon in system tray > tick/untick Presentation mode.

**To Add a Keybinding toggle:**
Command to toggle Presentation Mode:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/presentation-mode -T
```

Will bind this to Windows Key + P in following file

```
~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

added keybinding to file

```
<keybind key="W-p">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/presentation-mode -T</command>
      </action>
</keybind>
```

can logoff/logon then use Windows Key + P to toggle to keep your screen on when watching movies or displaying powerpoint presentations etc